# Fourier Transform of $e^{i \sinh x}$

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I am trying to compute the following integral

$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i \omega x} e^{i k^2 \sinh(x)} dx
$$

with $k^2$ a positive, real constant.

For $k^2 = 1$, one can compute this integral numerically on Mathematica with seeming great precision. The imaginary part of the integral vanishes due to a parity argument, and the plot of the real part of the integral as a function of $\omega$ is produced here: [Image of the Fourier transform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaF0l.jpg). Because the plot looks quite nice, I hope that one might express this Fourier transform in terms of some known functions. I have been able to prove via saddle point methods that the Fourier transform decays exponentially in $\omega$ as $\omega \rightarrow \pm \infty$ and have shown rigorously that the Fourier transform is bounded for any choice of $k^2$. Nevertheless, the actual answer (if there is, indeed, a nice expression) continues to evade me. I have tried to compute the Fourier transform of $\exp(ik^2 e^{\pm \theta})$ in effort to use the convolution theorem to derive the final result. Unfortunately, this method ultimately leads to an integral of a product of $\Gamma$ functions, which seems even more challenging. I have also tried a few more standard tricks with no success.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

P.S. In fact, I am ultimately hoping to compute the more general integral

$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i \omega x} e^{i k^2 \sinh(x)} \frac{\cosh(x + i \pi \alpha)}{\cosh(x)}dx
$$

where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R},$ but the $\alpha = 0$ case of the first integral may be an easier place to start. Thoughts in this direction would be particularly helpful.

Comment: I highly doubt there is a nice expression ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone else is interested, I have since been able to work out a "nice" closed-form expression for this integral. It turns out that it is related to a sum of Bessel functions of imaginary order and evaluated at imaginary values of z.

A complete derivation is worked out in Section 5.1 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/2210.16861.pdf.